# How to add button on Augmented Reality for IOS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried simple html, css coding for AR buttons. It'll work fine with Android but the buttons didn't appear in iOS. I don't know the issue. Can someone with it as i'm stuck in these for almost 2 days didn't find any solution.
i put the screenshots of IOS and Android..

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Google Sans, Noto, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  color: #244376;
}

#card {
  margin: 3em auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 600px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  overflow: hidden;
}

model-viewer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #70BCD1;
}

.attribution {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1em;
}

.attribution h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0.25em;
}

.attribution img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 2em;
}

.attribution .cc {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.btn-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: #edda73;
  height: 25px;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <div id="card">
      <!-- All you need to put beautiful, interactive 3D content on your site: -->
      <model-viewer
        src="https://cdn.glitch.com/36cb8393-65c6-408d-a538-055ada20431b/Astronaut.glb?1542147958948"
        ios-src="https://cdn.glitch.com/36cb8393-65c6-408d-a538-055ada20431b/Astronaut.usdz?v=1569545377878"
        quick-look-browsers="safari chrome"
        alt="A 3D model of an astronaut"
        shadow-intensity="1"
        camera-controls
        auto-rotate
        ar
      >
        <div class="btn-container">
          <button onclick="play()" type="button">Play</button>
          <button onclick="pause()" type="button">Pause</button>
          <button onclick="stop()" type="button">Stop</button>
        </div>
      </model-viewer>
    </div>

      <!--     <section class="attribution">
      <span>
        <h1>Astronaut</h1>
        <span>By <a href="https://poly.google.com/view/dLHpzNdygsg" target="_blank">Poly</a></span>
      </span>
      <a class="cc" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/icons/cc.svg">
        <img src="https://mirrors.creativecommons.org/presskit/icons/by.svg">
      </a>
    </section> -->
    </div>

  </body>
```

Android View

It is Show Perfect, In AR view buttons are shows..

[image]

IOS View

In IOS run complite but in AR 3 buttons not show like Android....

[image]